# I am trying to put text in squares but when i do the text apears in the middle and padding won't fix it

Tags: html, css

[image]

I'm trying to make this 4 squares with the words in them but when I gave them the size and shape I wanted and typed the words, they were bellow where they are in the image, so I tried adding padding -20px to the css code but it isn't working. Any idea why or any better solution? Also if you see something that can be improved in the html please let me know because I wasn't sure if this was an ok way to do it.

html

```html
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>uno</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1>dos</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1>tres</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1>cuatro</h1>
    </div>    
</body>
```

css

```css
div {
    background-color: red;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;

    color: yellow;
    font-size: x-large;
    padding-top: -50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the parent div's position as relative and H1 position as absolute.

```css
div {
    background-color: red;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    position:relative;
    color: yellow;
    font-size: x-large;
    padding-top: -50px;
}

h1{
position:absolute;
top:10px;
left:0px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>uno</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1>dos</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1>tres</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1>cuatro</h1>
    </div>    
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked but do you have any idea why the padding wasn't working? Just to understand :)

Comment: you cant put negative padding without adding a position property into your CSS. that's the problem :-)